# How to render absolute URL in asp .net mvc 2 view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

In AS:NET / Mono MVC2 method below form  [Render a view as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string) is used to create html e-mail bodies.

Partiil view Order.ascx contains images like

```
    <img width='20%' alt='' src='<%= Url.Action("Logo", "Store")%>' />
```

In Emails those images appear without site address like `/Store/Logo` and thus images do not appear.
How to force image links to appear with absolute addresses like `htttp:/Mysite.com/Store/Logo` or add site base address to html email body is this helps.

ASP.NET / Mono MVC2 , .NET 3.5, jquery, jquery ui are used.

Controller Action method:

```
        var s = RenderViewToString<OrderConfirm>("~/Views/Checkout/Order.ascx", order);

public class ControllerBase : Controller
{
    protected string RenderViewToString<T>(string viewPath, T model)
    { 
        ViewData.Model = model;
        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            var view = new WebFormView(viewPath);
            var vdd = new ViewDataDictionary<T>(model);
            var viewCxt = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, view, vdd, new TempDataDictionary(), writer);
            viewCxt.View.Render(viewCxt, writer);
            return writer.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the [`proper overload`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505232%28v=vs.108%29.aspx):

```
<%= Url.Action("Logo", "Store", null, "http") %>
```

Since we've specified the protocol, the helper will generate an absolute url. Also if you don't want to hardcode it you could read it from the current request:

```
<%= Url.Action("Logo", "Store", null, Request.Url.Scheme) %>
```

Now this will work for both standard and HTTPS schemes depending on how the view is requested.

Comment: Same view is also used in site to show order in browser. In this case absolute addresses appear is browser also. Is this OK ?

Comment: Yeah, it's fine. No problems with that.

Comment: You just don't want to hard-code absolute URLs, there's nothing wrong with using them other than that, so as long as they're generated, every link could be absolute for all it matters.